# How can I download a script using Javascript and supply a header to the GET?

Tags: javascript

I have this method for downloading a script:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("src", url);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

This gives me a GET like this:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:17315/Scripts/abc.js HTTP/1.1
```

However I need to add a header:

```
Authorization: Bearer Ipnsfm9h1MWYIM0n1ng
```

Can anyone tell me how I can add a header when I am using Javascript to perform the GET?  Please note I'm looking for a javascript only solution that does not use external libraries. Thanks

Comment: You'll probably need to switch to using `XMLHttpRequest`, which has a `setRequestHeader` method.

Comment: @icktoofay - Did you provide an answer for this? Some people commented but I cannot see your answer. Thanks

Comment: No, I did not provide an answer. I just provided a little nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ictoofay already answered, i have no reputation to comment.

**WAY - 1**

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/Scripts/Pages/Home.js", false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Custom-Header", "My Values");
xmlhttp.send();

    var m = document.createElement('script');
    m.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xmlhttp.responseText));
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(m);
```

TEST : http://www.renewpage.com/TestXMLHttpRequest/

**WAY - 2** WITH JQUERY

```
$.getScript = function (url,f) {
  $.ajax({
    url:url,
    success:f,
    dataType:"script",
    headers:{"X-Custom-Header":"My Values"}
  });
};

$.getScript("/Scripts/Pages/Home.js",function(){ alert("...")});
```

if you want do it for your all requests

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers:{"X-Custom-Header":"My Values"}
});
```

Comment: Robbert i'm a beginner at so, thank you for your interest. I've edited. icktoofay has answered but i don't want to delete my answer. then i've added alternative.

Comment: @marathonman - If I use your first solution then where is the javascript stored? I thought I would have to do a GET and then attach it to some part of the DOM for later use? Please note I'm not looking for a jQuery solution. I just added another line to the question to clarify this. thanks

Comment: Alan, for anything to work, you need to have some form of .js already loaded. That .js can then load another .js. It won't magically happen otherwise.

Comment: @Alan i've added three new lines. working example : http://www.renewpage.com/TestXMLHttpRequest/

Comment: @marathonman - Thanks. I'm confused with Alexis's comment where he says I need to have some form of .js already loaded. Is that correct? I don't see your code using any .js library.

Comment: @Alan it's better to ask Alexis. i've tested again, both ways will work for you. could you please check with web debugging tool like devtools or fiddler.